# Get notified when new email arrives in Gmail?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail, imap, google-oauth

I am writing an application in which i am downloading emails from My google account using OAuth over IMap. I am periodically connecting to the account and checking if any new mail arrives to download.
Is there any notification system available which will send a message to my client whenever new message reached inbox?

Comment: Please research IMAP IDLE.

Comment: Right, see the [IMAPFolder.idle](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#idle()) method.  It requires that your client maintain an open connection to the server to wait for notification.